# How to properly use the aes cbc api from mbedtls

Tags: c++, aes, mbedtls

My current approach doesn't even produce the correct encrypted data as checked against golang's aes implementation. It also doesn't decrypt back to the original plaintext, but that's expected if the encryption step isn't working correctly. My best guess is that I'm misusing the api somehow. This is a self-contained example and can run as is.

```
#include <mbedtls/aes.h>

#include <vector>

void LogVec(const std::vector<uint8_t>& bin)
{
    printf("(size: %i) ", bin.size());
    printf("{");
    for (auto& b : bin)
    {
        printf("%#02x, ", b);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

mbedtls_aes_context AesContext;

std::vector<uint8_t> EncryptAes(std::vector<uint8_t>& iv, std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> ivCpy(iv);

    uint8_t padByte = 16 - (data.size() % 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < padByte; i++)
        data.push_back(padByte);

    std::vector<uint8_t> ret(data.size());
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&AesContext, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, data.size(), ivCpy.data(), data.data(), ret.data());

    return ret;
}

std::vector<uint8_t> DecryptAes(const std::vector<uint8_t>& iv, std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> ivCpy(iv);

    std::vector<uint8_t> ret(data.size());
    mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc(&AesContext, MBEDTLS_AES_DECRYPT, data.size(), ivCpy.data(), data.data(), ret.data());

    ret.resize(ret.size() - ret[ret.size() - 1]);
    
    return ret;
}

int main() 
{
    mbedtls_aes_init(&AesContext);

    std::vector<uint8_t> data = { 0x3b, 0xb1, 0x99, 0x3, 0x67, 0xf3, 0x2e, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x67, 0x38, 0xc9, 0x53, 0x92, 0xa4 };

    std::vector<uint8_t> key = { 0x15, 0x1, 0xc0, 0xd0, 0xe4, 0xfd, 0xdf, 0xd7, 0x7a, 0x65, 0xf1, 0x2f, 0x45, 0x61, 0xb, 
        0x59, 0xd9, 0xa, 0x9c, 0x61, 0xc, 0x4, 0x76, 0xdb, 0xb, 0xbe, 0x9e, 0xe4, 0x7f, 0x8d, 0xe1, 0x46 };

    std::vector<uint8_t> iv = { 0xa2, 0x78, 0xc9, 0xa4, 0xd8, 0x34, 0x88, 0x9b, 0x28, 0xdc, 0xb9, 0xe2, 0xc0, 0x58, 0x8c, 0xbc };

    mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc(&AesContext, key.data(), 256);
    mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec(&AesContext, key.data(), 256);

    std::vector<uint8_t> dataEnc = EncryptAes(iv, data);
    printf("Encrypted data: ");
    LogVec(dataEnc);

    //std::vector<uint8_t> dataDec = DecryptAes(iv, dataEnc);
    //printf("Decrypted data: ");
    //LogVec(dataDec);

    getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
Encrypted data: (size: 16) {0x5d, 0x1c, 0x9, 0x2e, 0x92, 0x8e, 0x24, 0x43, 0xfa, 0xaf, 0xb3, 0xf5, 0x37, 0x8, 0x99, 0x93, }
```

Expected output from using the same key, iv, data in golang:

```
Encrypted: 34730cba3543e5facf4b94ba9dc8a275
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc` to encrypt you should call `mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc` and before calling `mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc` to decrypt you should call `mbedtls_aes_setkey_dec`. When both are called at initialization like in your code, the latter call to `setkey_dec` will overwrite important data in the context structure set by `setkey_enc` required for encryption.